# Login With Facebook Button do not work

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

Currently, I am using this code for login with Facebook link:

```
<?php <a href="'.htmlspecialchars($loginURL).'">Login With Facebook</a> ?>
```

It works perfectly fine. But I am trying to use [official login with facebook button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web/login-button)

I placed this code, at the starting of body tag:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.9&appId=15885xxxxx491691";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

And using this where i want the button to appear:

```
<div class="fb-login-button" data-max-rows="1" data-size="medium" data-button-type="login_with" data-show-faces="false" data-auto-logout-link="false" data-use-continue-as="false"></div>
```

But when i click on the button, It pop-up a new window (to facebook), and then close itself within 1 sec. That's all.

Do i need to change the URL in Javascript or something?

I tried to change the URL in java script like this:

```
  <?php echo'js.src = "';  echo htmlspecialchars($loginURL);    echo '";';  ?>
```

But then even the login button do not show up

Comment: Check This... https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web

Comment: I saw that (also provided a link to it). But still i am facing this problem @RïshïKêshKümar sir

Comment: _“But when i click on the button, It pop-up a new window (to facebook), and then close itself within 1 sec. That's all.”_ - works as designed ... If the user has already logged in to the app before, and you are not asking for any new permissions ... then this is the _expected_ behavior.

Comment: But when i click on the link, it do not open an new window + it works. 

the fb login button, just open a window, and then after closing itself, it do not log me in